# bruteforcing keepassxc with bash

Tags: bash, scripting, pipe, stdin

I have forgotten part of my password to Keepassxc database (.kdbx with keyfile). The password consists of 20 symbols, 17 of which are known. I have generated the list of all possible combinations using the characters I believe to be used in the unknown part of the password (they are put into charlist.txt) and following small one-liner:

```
for i in $(cat charlist.txt); do
  for j in $(cat charlist.txt); do
    for k in $(cat charlist); do
      echo $a$i$j$k
    done
  done
done > output.txt
```

Keepassxc allows me to read a password from stdin (either with `keepassxc --pw-stdin` or with `keepassxc-cli`; the first one opens the GUI with the stdin input and the second one asks for input in the usual form "enter the password"). However, I cannot wrap my head around the way to do it iteratively. There are 5832 lines in output.txt, which makes manual bruteforcing unfeasible.

How can I pass either the contents of the output.txt or the one-liner output to the keepassxc?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
while read p; do
         echo "$p" | keepassxc --pw-stdin; 
done <output.txt
```

I don't know the behavior of keepassxc when receiving a wrong input. Maybe be prepared for 5831 open error windows.